# Prove that the integral of an even function is odd

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm given the function$$F(x)=\int \limits _0^xf(t)\,dt$$and that $f(t)$ is an even function. The assignment asks me to prove that $F(x)$ is an odd function.

I've tried doing something like$$F(-x)=\int \limits _0^{-x}f(-t)\,dt=\int \limits _0^{-x}f(t)\,dt=-\int \limits _{-x}^0f(t)\,dt$$and now since $f(t)$ is even the area in the intervals $[-x,0]$ and $[0,x]$ should be the same,but I'm not sure whether this is a rigorous enough proof. Any tips?

Comment: Use the substitution $u=-x$.

Comment: Don't use the same symbol for the integration variable and the upper limit. It's so easy to make mistakes. When you write $F(-x) = \int_0^{-x} f(-x)dx$ it looks like you take $x\to -x$ both in the upper limit and in the integrand (and this is wrong). If you did this then it does not give an error here but just because $f$ is even. If you instead write $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t){\rm d}t$ then it's unambigious that $F(-x) = \int_0^{-x}f(t){\rm d}t$.

Comment: Yes,that was a mistake of mine.Thanks

Comment: I would go the other way!  The DERIVATIVE of an even function is odd and the derivative of an odd function is an even function.  If f is even then f(-x)= f(x).  Differentiating, -f'(-x)=  F'(x) so f'(-x)= -f'(x)  and f'(x) is an odd function.

Answer (score 9):

We have
$$
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt,
$$
then
$$F(-x) =\int_{0}^{-x}f(t)dt=\overbrace{ \int_{0}^{x}f(-u)(-du)}^{\large u\:=-t}=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)(-du)=-F(x).$$

Comment: Better, I would say, to use a new variable for the substitution, e.g. $u=-t$. To you and me, it's clear that the result is the same, but then it wasn't you or me who asked the question.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that
$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_0^{x}f(t)\;dt\tag{definition of $F$}\\\\
&=\int_0^{x}f(-t)\;dt\tag{$f$ is even}\\\\
&=-\int_0^{-x}f(s)\;ds\tag{substitution $s=-t$}\\\\
&=-F(-x)\tag{definition of $F$}
\end{align}$$
and thus
$$F(-x)=-F(x)$$

Answer (score -1):

I would go the other way!  The DERIVATIVE of an even function is odd and the derivative of an odd function is an even function.  If f is even then f(-x)= f(x).  Differentiating, -f'(-x)=  F'(x) so f'(-x)= -f'(x)  and f'(x) is an odd function.  If f is odd then f(-x)= -f(x).  Differetiating, -f'(-x)= -f'(x) so f'(-x)= f(x) and f' s an even function.  That can be rephrased as "if' is odd then f is even and if f' is even then f is odd".  Since integration is the inverse operation to differentiation, replacing f' with f and r with $\int f dx$"  we  have "if f is odd the $\int f dx$ is even and if f is even $\int f dx$ is odd'.

Comment: "That can be rephrased as [...]" - No, [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent) is still an invalid argument.  Within the context of this question, the important implication of "If $f'$ is even then $f$ is odd" is false, and instead it would need to be "If $f'$ is even and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is odd".