# For an even and $2\pi$ periodic function, why does $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx $

Tags: integration

How does one derive the fact that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx $$ whenever $f(x)$ is an even and $2\pi$ periodic function. I do know the result that for even functions, we have $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$$
But for the case where the end points are not symmetrical wrt the origin i do not know how to do.

Comment: If $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic then $\int_{[-\pi, \pi]}f(x)dx=\int_{[0, 2\pi]}f(x)dx$.

Comment: Maybe it helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438691/how-does-knowing-a-function-as-even-or-odd-help-in-integration and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606977/prove-that-the-integral-of-an-even-function-is-odd

Comment: Why not graph the function, say for $a=3$ and $b=2$ and check the symmetry at $\pi$

Comment: This is way better now, after the editing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

We have,

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b \cos x} dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b \cos (x-2\pi)} dx$$

Can you see why? What happens if you let $x-2\pi=u$ on the second part?

> \begin{align} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx \ =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx \ =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos (x-2\pi)}dx \ =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx+\int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x} dx \ =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx \ =2 \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx \end{align}

Comment: Hello, for your first part you can do this because $\cos x$ is even, so you basically replaced $\cos(x)$ with $\cos(x-2\pi)$, however after i followed your step to do substitution i can only get to $\int_{-2\pi}^{0}\frac{1}{a+b\cos(u)}du$.

Comment: For the first step I used $\int_{0}^{\pi}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$ and the fact cosine is $2\pi$ periodic to write $\cos x=\cos (x-2\pi)$. You should do substitution on only the second part this gives $\int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{1}{a+b\cos u} du$. Let me know if you still have questions @ilovewt

Comment: Oh i got it, the key thing in the substitution is that $du = dx$ and hence our result will not change. Thank you as i cannot visualize this by diagrams since $2\pi$ to $0$ is not symmetric about origin.

Comment: You're welcome, in general if $f$ is even and $2\pi$ periodic the same argument shows $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f=\int_{0}^{\pi} f+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x-2\pi)=\int_{0}^{\pi} f+\int_{-\pi}^{0} f=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f=2\int_{0}^{\pi} f$

Comment: Ok so it holds for $\sin$ function too!

Comment: No it doesn't because $\sin $ isn't event but you can say $\int_{0}^{2\pi}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$ in that case. I hope that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

For an even function $f(x)$, the statement $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$ is **not** generally true. Counterexample:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^2dx = \frac{8\pi^3}{3} \ne2\int_{0}^{\pi}x^2dx = \frac{2\pi^3}{3}.$$

However, if an even function is $2\pi$ periodic, $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$, then

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx.$$

A verbal argument for the first equality in the prior line is that we're still integrating over one period of the function, so the integral is invariant. You can achieve the transformation via substitutions like in Ahmed's answer.