# Prove that $\int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$ is an odd function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$ is an odd function.

$$\Rightarrow \int_0^{-x} e^{-t^2} dt = -\int_0^{x} e^{-t^2} dt$$

I don't know how to continue from here

Comment: It is well known in **general** that if we consider $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)~dt$ and [given that $f(t)$ is even, then $F(x)$ is certainly an odd function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606977/prove-that-the-integral-of-an-even-function-is-odd). And it is very easy to prove that $f(t)=e^{-t^2}$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substitution $t=-u$ to obtain
$$\int_0^{-x} e^{-t^2} dt = \int_0^x e^{-(-u)^2} \cdot (-1)\, du = \int_0^x -e^{-u^2}\,du = -\int_0^x e^{-u^2}\, du$$

Answer (score 1):

The arrow $\text{“}\Rightarrow\text{''}$ should be used only either in things like $A\Rightarrow B$ meaning “If $A$ then $B$”, or in $\text{“} \Rightarrow B\text{''}$ meaning $\text{“ }$from the foregoing we can conclude $B.\text{”}$

$$
f(-x) = \int_0^{-x} e^{-t^2}\,dt = - \int_{-x}^0 e^{-t^2}\,dt.
$$
Now let $u=-t$ so $du = -dt.$ As $t$ goes from $-x$ to $0$, then $u$ goes from $x$ to $0.$ Therefore
$$
-\int_{-x}^0 e^{-t^2}\,dt = -\int_x^0 e^{-(-u)^2} (-du) = \int_x^0 e^{-u^2} \,du = - \int_0^x e^{-u^2}\, du = -f(x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2}\ dt + \int\limits_0^{-x} e^{-t^2}\ dt = \int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2}\ dt - \int\limits_0^{x} e^{-t^2}\ dt = 0$ because the integrand is symmetric.